# SSH ProxyJump checks for id_rsa on local machine instead of Proxy server

Tags: ssh, proxy, visual-studio-code

I want to set up a SSH connection to remote server that is behid a proxy within the ~/.shh/config file. Curently my file looks like this:

```
Host Proxy
HostName proxy_server_address
User JhonDoe    

Host internal_machine
HostName internal_address
User JhonDoe
ProxyJump Proxy
```

When doing `ssh internal_machine` this configuration asks me for a password for Proxy server and then for a password for `internal_machine`. However I already have the `id_rsa` for the `internal_machine` on `Proxy` and it should ssh to it without requesting the password. When observing the logs with "ssh -v" I saw that when ssh is executed on Proxy it checks for the id_rsa key on my local machine instead of `Proxy`. Is there any way to configure `ProxyJump` to check for `id_rsa` key on Proxy server instead of my local machine?

The desired functionality I am looking for is that when doing `ssh internal_machine` from my local machine it will ask me for `Proxy` password and then automaticaly log me to `internal_machine`

NOTE 1:
If I copy `id_rsa` from `Proxy` to my local machine this works, but as I understand this is not a good practice regarding security

NOTE 2: I am doing this because I want to use VisualStudio Code's remote SSH development capabilities and all this needs to be configured in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b) seems related.

Comment: This is inherent to how `ProxyJump` works. It makes an ssh connection from your computer to the proxy server, and then a second connection *from your computer* to the internal machine (tunneled over the first connection). Since both connections start from your computer, the private keys need to be on your computer. BTW, I'm not sure why having both keys on the client (and none at all on the proxy server) would be considered a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you @GordonDavisson for the explanation, it resolves my question. In my oppinion you can change it to an answer and I will accept it. Regarding the security risk I was just thinking that my local machine is more likely to get stolen/broken into than the proxy server.

Comment: @singalongconflict Yes it is related, and I will try to configure it in that way, but I had some problems before with the ProxyCommand and ProxyJump worked, just not exactly the way I wanted, this is why I wanted to check if there is any way to make ProxyJump work.